# can not see siebel object while SiebelAx is open at task manager

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I spent many time to solve it but i couldn't, could you please help?

Siebel add-in is installed, i can see SiebelAx at task manager, but when i try to spy object, uft recognize them as web objects not siebel obejct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but the following might help

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/siebel-answers/my-siebel-qtp-journey-part-1-setup-41540

Comment: this article is about how to open SiebelAx_Test_A at task manager. I am facing that problem after SiebelAx_Test_A start where article stops

Comment: There are 4 articles in total...I worked on Siebel a year ago and this came in handy...I am posting the link of  4th article which contains all other links as well, see if it helps. [link](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/siebel-answers/my-siebel-qtp-journey-part-4-making-siebel-login-generic-42764)